# Creating a table with results of two findall calls using Rally SDK 1.33

Tags: javascript, html, sdk, rally

I would like to recreate Rally's Iteration Summary app. Therefore, I would like to be able to display information about defects, iterations, etc... in one UI component. Currently, I have two tables (one displaying results of a findall for defects, one displaying the results of a findall for iterations). Any way to have one findall to get results for both of these? Or is there another way to access results of multiple findall calls in one Rally UI component (meaning one table would be able to display results of findall(s) for iterations and the associated defects)? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full example of a AppSDK 1.33 app that makes two queries, and builds a single table of two different artifacts, defects and stories based on a selection in the Iteration dropdown:

User Stories By Iteration Example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.33/sdk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    rallyDataSource = null;
    iterDropdown    = null;

    function showTable(results) {
        for (var i=0; i < results.stories.length; i++) {
    results.stories[i].Project = results.stories[i].Project.Name
        }

        var tableConfig = {
            columnKeys   : ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'ScheduleState', 'Project' ],
            columnWidths : ['80px','80px', '80px','80px']
        };
        var table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(tableConfig);
        table.addRows(results.stories);
    table.addRows(results.defects);
        table.display(document.getElementById('myTable'));
    }

    function onIterationSelected() {
        document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = "";
    var queryConfig = [];      
        queryConfig[0] = {
            type : 'hierarchicalrequirement',
            key  : 'stories',
            fetch: 'FormattedID,Name,Project,ScheduleState',
            query: '(Iteration.Name = "' + iterDropdown.getSelectedName() + '")',
            order: 'Rank'
        };
     queryConfig[1] = {
            type : 'defect',
            key  : 'defects',
            fetch: 'FormattedID,Name,Project,ScheduleState',
            query: '(Iteration.Name = "' + iterDropdown.getSelectedName() + '")',
            order: 'Rank'
        };

        rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, showTable);
    }

    function onLoad() {
//USE VALID OIDs 
        rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('111111',
                                                             '22222',
                                                             'false',
                                                             'true');
        var iterConfig = {label : ""};
        iterDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.IterationDropdown(iterConfig, rallyDataSource);
        iterDropdown.display(document.getElementById("iterationDiv"), onIterationSelected);
    }

    rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);
</script>
```

Select Iteration

There is another example of a [placeholder query](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/data-examples#Placeholder%20Query) in AppSDK 1.x documentation.
It is a little harder to imagine a single table populated with all defects and all iterations - those two objects are too different to share a table meaningfully. The Iteration Summary app your mention does not have a single table for them - the iterations are listed there in a separate dropdown field. But it meaningfully combines data from defects and test cases - something similar to the app above that shows defects and stories.

Comment: Yes this was along the lines of what I was looking for. Can't believe I didn't think to try an array of queries! Thanks